# How to check test quality with Sonar?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Currently, we are using Sonar to check the quality of our production code. I would Like to check the quality of the test Code either.

How can I do it ?

I tried to change the "sonar.sources" to include test, but in this case i have an error : test folders are defined twice, one in test and one in source.

May be I can configure sonar / maven / jenkins to run 2 analysis : first one, the src code, with the test coverage, thant the tests (only quality, no coverage). But I also need to have everything run in a single jenkins job and displayed in a single Sonar Project.

And I don't know where to configure (pom ? sonar ? jenkins ?) I found some things about profiles, but it seems to be deprecated for my version.

I'm using Sonar 5.1, run from a jenkins job.

our Sonar properties in the pom are :

```
<project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>
<run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
<sonar-maven-plugin.version>2.6</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
<sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/assets/**/*.*,
src/main/webapp/bower_components/**/*.*,
src/main/webapp/dist/**/*.*</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>
<sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/karma</sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>
<sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>

<sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sonar.sources>
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
<sonar.tests>${project.basedir}/src/test/</sonar.tests>
```

Comment: You know that test code is usually 100% covered. Why would you want to cover that? For quality, you can run static code analysis tools (PMD, CheckStyle, FindBugs, CodeNarc etc). For code coverage, all that matters is what's sonar.sources, sonar.tests and sonar.java.binaries (sonar.binaries) specially the last one. If you provide that with value like target/classes/* you'll see that Duplicate/defined twice error. Try setting sonar.sources=src/main, sonar.tests=src/test etc and first, sonar.binaries(sonar.java.binaries) to target/classes/main and get coverage. Then, try with target/classes/test

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of the Java plugin there are some rules to check tests, but they are test-specific rules. I.E. they check if your `@Test` methods contain assertions &etc. You simply need to add those rules to your profile.

If, however, you're talking about running "code rules" on your tests, then your best bet is probably to define another project where the tests are treated as sources. Since you've already noted the difficulties of doing that with Maven, I would use [SonarQube Scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) for this separate, second analysis.